# Calling an external program in Julia - IOError

Tags: julia

I'm working on some tests for a package I'm writing and I'd like to call an external program. I've read through the "[Running External Programs](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/running-external-programs/)" section of the docs and it seems like it should be pretty simple.

My program is on the path, so I can navigate to a given directory and run `beamdyn beamfile.inp`, and it works as expected.
When I start up julia in that same directory and run `` run(`beamdyn beamfile.inp`) `` I get the following error:

```
ERROR: IOError: could not spawn `beamdyn beamfile.inp`: no such file or directory (ENOENT)
```

I don't think it has something to do with quotes, but I've tried different variations using quotes. It's almost like julia can't see my path in the shell.... but I don't actually know tons about shell or the inner workings of julia, so feel free to correct. How do I run the program from within julia? Or do I just have to run the programs externally?

I forgot to inlcude my OS: MacOS 13.3.1 (22E261).

Comment: What OS are you on? `ENV["PATH"]` is the PATH as Julia sees it. Can you verify whether `beamdyn`'s path is in there? It might be that your shell has `beamdyn`s path in its PATH, but doesn't export it to subprocesses (like Julia). If so (and assuming you're on Linux), you might need to `export PATH` before running Julia.

Comment: Fair point, I forgot to include my OS. MacOS 13.3.1 (22E261)
The directory that has the executable `beamdyn` is on my ENV["PATH"], do I need to directly point to the executable? I'll give the export a try.

Comment: Running `export PATH` before starting Julia up didn't seem to change anything.

Comment: You could make a symlink to the same directory of your julia script and then run `cd(@__DIR__)` before the `run` command..